# Jquery fade in and out between color and BW image

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I m trying to have on hover to fade the colored image to black and white image. so what I was thinking to do is to use JqueryUI switchClass and fade between two classes

here is my CSS :

```
 img.grayscale {
 filter: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns=\'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\'><filter     id=\'grayscale\'><feColorMatrix type=\'matrix\' values=\'0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0 0 0 1 0\'/></filter>    </svg>#grayscale"); /* Firefox 10+, Firefox on Android */
 filter: gray; /* IE6-9 */
-webkit-filter: grayscale(100%); /* Chrome 19+, Safari 6+, Safari 6+ iOS */
 }
```

this is the class which will make the image B& W

I have an image here :

```
<div class="thumbnail">
    <img  src="/images/colored.jpg" class="img"/>
   </div>
```

My Jquery code is :

```
 $('.thumbnail').mouseover(function(){
$('.img').switchClass( "img", "grayscale", 1000, "easeOutBounce" )
  });
 $('.thumbnail').mouseout(function(){
$('.img').switchClass( "grayscale", "img", 1000, "easeInOutQuad" )
 });
```

its not working , its not fading in and out smoothly , could someone help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You don't need a jquery for that. You can use css.

```
img.grayscale{ 
filter: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns=\'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\'><filter id=\'grayscale\'><feColorMatrix type=\'matrix\' values=\'0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0 0 0 1 0\'/></filter></svg>#grayscale"); /* Firefox 10+, Firefox on Android */
    filter: grayscale(100%);
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);  /* For Webkit browsers */
    filter: gray;  /* For IE 6 - 9 */
    -webkit-transition: all .6s ease;  /* Transition for Webkit browsers */
}
img.grayscale:hover{ 
 filter: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns=\'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\'><filter id=\'grayscale\'><feColorMatrix type=\'matrix\' values=\'1 0 0 0 0, 0 1 0 0 0, 0 0 1 0 0, 0 0 0 1 0\'/></filter></svg>#grayscale");
    filter: grayscale(0%);
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(0%);
    filter: none;
}
```

Here your html tag should be

```
<div class="thumbnail">
    <img  src="/images/colored.jpg" class="img grayscale"/>
</div>
```

This solution is quite simple and I find it effective to use across multiple browsers. It simply uses the `:hover` and `filter` in the css to avoid all the jquery stuff.

source: http://www.cheesetoast.co.uk/add-grayscale-images-hover-css-black-white/

Comment: +1 - You should give a bit of explanation of *how and why* this works.

Comment: Edited. Not sure how much needed to be explained as it's pretty straight forward.

Comment: does this fade out slowly to the grey ?

Comment: I cant get it to delay more , how to do that I need to slowly make it fade

Comment: `-webkit-transition: all .6s ease;` change it to say 1s or 2s will slow down the fading. Let me know if this works

Comment: still not delaying or fading

Comment: @user3150060 which browser are you using?

Comment: I guessed so. I've tried but yet to find a solution for transition animation on FF. This grayscale technique works on ALL browser, however the animation part only works on webkit browsers that includes Chrome, Safari and Opera.

Comment: ya I tried it with different browser and its working , is there away to fix it for FF

Comment: I don't think there is a good way to fix this though check this out http://stackoverflow.com/a/21258787/3421070. Menno has an interesting hacky way that you can fix it, which I've never tried.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need javascript:

```
img.grayscale{-webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease;}
img.grayscale:hover {
    filter: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns=\'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\'><filter     id=\'grayscale\'><feColorMatrix type=\'matrix\' values=\'0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0 0 0 1 0\'/></filter>    </svg>#grayscale"); /* Firefox 10+, Firefox on Android */
    filter: gray; /* IE6-9 */
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%); /* Chrome 19+, Safari 6+, Safari 6+ iOS */
}
```

Hope that helps

Comment: on ie 9+ it sure will

Comment: yes I looked at it , but for some reason its not delaying it happens too fast

Comment: try increasing the time like 1s instead of .4s and try using the ease-in-out at the end